# How do I bring the task bar from the top of the screen down?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

When I was cleaning my mouse, I accidentally moved the taksbar to the top of the screen. I remember that in previous versions of windows, I could just drag it down, but it's not working right now. How do I bring it back down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the taskbar, uncheck "lock the taskbar" and drag it down. To prevent unlocking it again, right click it again and click "lock taskbar".

Comment: Stage. The taskbar appears to have been locked when it moved... Anyway, this solved the problem.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: Yeah, there is a small bug where it does not perform the lock check.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag it back into place. You should also right click it and make sure that the taskbar isn't locked.